# Tengo problemas con mi codificación de caracteres en mi base de datos!

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Amigos, como puedo hacer para que la db me contemple los acentos y no me ponga el signo de "?", en el html tengo el utf8 y en la db tengo el cotejamiento de utf8_spanish2_ci, pero nose que me falte para que me contemple los acentos y las ñ.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te invito a leer **[ask]** y según los consejos que se te dan ahí edites la pregunta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad

Comment: que gestor de base de datos estas empleando mysql??

Comment: Intenta usar en el charset de la BD **utf8** y en la collation **utf8_spanish2_ci**

Comment: En caso de que no sea ese el problema, intenta con la codificacion en tu html, ya que sino mantienen la misma codificacion tanto la BD como el html, te seguira mostrando los signos de ?

Answer (score 2):

Creo que [esto](https://xaviesteve.com/354/acentos-y-enes-aparecen-mal-a%C2%B1-en-php-con-mysql-utf-8-iso-8859-1/) puede resolver tu problema.

Cotejamiento
Al crear la base de datos MySQL, asegúrate que los campos string y demás esten en utf8_spanish_ci y el cotejamiento de las tablas en utf_unicode_ci (más tarde en Operations > Collation de phpMyAdmin se puede cambiar)
Content type HTML
Pon en el  de todos los archivos HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Content type PHP
Y en los puramente PHP (que muestran XML, llamadas de AJAX, APIs…) pon el código:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

Set names
Al crear la conexión de PHP con MySQL, envía esta consulta justo tras la conexión:

```
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Para MySQLi escribe:

```
`$acentos = $db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); `
```

Convertir codificado a UTF-8
Convierte todo lo que esté codificado de latin1 a UTF-8 (gracias Guillermo)

```
SELECT convert(cast(convert(content using latin1) as binary) using utf8) AS content
```

Apache
Quita el DefaultCharset del Apache o modifícalo
htmlentities
Como última y desesperada opción, quita todos los htmlentities(); y sustitúyelo por otro parser para ‘sanitizar’ los datos.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/97216)

Comment: Perdón, ya la elimino

Comment: Me disculpo por mi respuesta anterior espero que con esta valga.